# Find ultimate parent of an entity using recursion in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, recursion, parent-child

I have an Entity which in turn refers to same table which is its parent. Below is the table which describes it more better.

```
| ID | Source_ID |
+----+----------+
| 1  | null     |
| 2  | 1        |
| 3  | 1        |
| 4  | 2        |
| 5  | 4        |
```

Now, when I am at ID = 5, I need to fetch its ultimate parent, which is ID = 1.

I tried writing a function which is as below:

```
<entity> ultimateparententity;
internal <entity> FetchParentComponentRecursive(<entity> entity)
 {
  if (component.ParentEntity!= null)
  {
     FetchParentComponentRecursive(entity.ParentEntity);
  }
  else
  {
     ultimateparententity = entity;
     return component;
  }
 return entity;
}
```

I am using variable declared at class level to know the ultimate parent. I am returning variable "Entity" which is never used later, but ultimateparententity is what is used. This approach works, but I am not too happy with this. Any directions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with C#, but the general structure of your recursive function looks off.

Try something along the lines of:

```
internal <entity> FetchParentComponentRecursive(<entity> entity)
{
  if (component.ParentEntity == null)
  {
     return component;
  }
  else
  {
     return FetchParentComponentRecursive(entity.ParentEntity);
  }
}
```

By the way, this very much depends on there being no circular references in your data set.

Comment: there are no circular reference in the DB. Will try this approach. Thanks :)